# I would like to know how to create etc groups in d3.js donut chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, grouping

I would like to know how to create etc groups in d3.js donut chart.

```
data = {{result|safe}}

      var text = "";

      var width = 1450;
      var height = 500;
      var thickness = 40;
      var duration = 750;

      var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

      var svg = d3.select("#donutchart")
      .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'pie')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

      var g = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width/2) + ',' + (height/2) + ')');

      var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(radius - thickness)
      .outerRadius(radius);

      var pie = d3.pie()
      .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
      .sort(null);

      var path = g.selectAll('path')
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            let g = d3.select(this)
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .style("fill", "black")
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "text-group");
       
            g.append("text")
              .attr("class", "name-text")
              .text(`${d.data.word}`)
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .attr('dy', '-1.2em');
        
            g.append("text")
              .attr("class", "value-text")
              .text(`${d.data.count}`)
              .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
              .attr('dy', '.6em');
          })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
              .style("cursor", "none")  
              .style("fill", color(this._current))
              .select(".text-group").remove();
          })
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', arc)
        .attr('fill', (d,i) => color(i))
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)     
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .style("fill", "black");
          })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
              .style("cursor", "none")  
              .style("fill", color(this._current));
          })
        .each(function(d, i) { this._current = i; });


      g.append('text')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.35em')
        .text(text);
```

When the number of word counts of data is less than 100, is there a way to show the chart by making it into an etc group? Does it have to be handled by the server?

Or is there a way to show only the top 8 data and make it into an etc group?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend the data is an array of objects with "name" and "value":

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "value": 198
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "value": 100
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "value": 50
  },
  // ...
]
```

We'll also assume it's sorted (you can do this like so):

```
var data = data.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value))
```

Let's take the 8 biggest values, and put all the rest in an "etc" label:

```
let newData = data.slice(0, 8)
const etcSliceAmount = data.slice(8, data.length-1)
  .map(d => d.value)
  .reduce((acc, x) => acc + x)
newData.push({
  name: "etc",
  value: etcSliceAmount,
})
```

In `etcSliceAmount`, we first get all the items except the first eight. We use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) to add them up to the sum. Finally, we can append this new partition at the end of our data. Since there's no sorting, disabled in your code with `sort(null)`, d3 will place the slices in order.

```js
// random array of 100 values from [0-200], sorted
const data = d3.range(100).map(() => ({
  name: "a", 
  value: Math.floor(d3.randomUniform(0, 200)())
})).sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value))

let newData = data.slice(0, 8)
const etcSliceAmount = data.slice(8, data.length-1).map(d => d.value).reduce((acc, x) => acc + x)
newData.push({
  name: "etc",
  value: etcSliceAmount,
})

console.log(newData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```